# Laravel 5.0 Eloquent Need query to list user, posts and related comments in facebook style

Tags: laravel-5

My table's fields are as below :

```
users :    id  email     first_name    last_name     (rest are there but need only these)
activity_stream :    id  user_id    post          created_at    updated_at  deleted_at
activity_stream_comments : id  post_id  user_id       comment       created_at  updated_at  deleted_at
```

I need listing of all the users posts with related comments just like you see in facebook, it shows various users posts with posts comments so for now I basically need to list down all the users posts with related comments.

I am trying the below query but it gives only the post that have comments that too in different sets :

```
$results = DB::table('activity_stream')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'activity_stream.user_id')
    ->join('activity_stream_comments', 'activity_stream.id', '=', 'activity_stream_comments.post_id')
    ->select('activity_stream.*', 'users.first_name','users.last_name', 'activity_stream_comments.comment')
    /*->where('activity_stream.user_id', $user_id)*/
->whereNull('activity_stream.deleted_at')
    ->orderBy('activity_stream.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

return response()->json($results);
```

And the return is  :

```
[
  {
    "id": "97",
    "user_id": "30",
    "post": "hi how are you?",
    "created_at": "2015-11-20 04:35:11",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-20 04:35:11",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "first_name": "Abhijan",
    "last_name": "Pal",
    "comment": "test"
  },
  {
    "id": "14",
    "user_id": "49",
    "post": "Test Post",
    "created_at": "2015-11-13 04:51:53",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-13 04:51:53",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "first_name": "Nazir",
    "last_name": "Hussain",
    "comment": "This is my first comment"
  },
  {
    "id": "14",
    "user_id": "49",
    "post": "Test Post",
    "created_at": "2015-11-13 04:51:53",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-13 04:51:53",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "first_name": "Nazir",
    "last_name": "Hussain",
    "comment": "This is my 2nd comment"
  }
]
```

---

**Improvement :**

```
$results = User::with('activity_stream.activity_stream_comments')->find($user_id);

return response()->json($results);
```

While using relationship and using above query I get the response as below  :

```
{
  "id": "49",
  "email": "nazir.2cool@gmail.com",
  "permissions": null,
  "last_login": "2015-11-19 09:32:36",
  "first_name": "Nazir",
  "last_name": "Hussain",
  "created_at": "2015-11-03 12:36:56",
  "updated_at": "2015-11-19 09:32:36",
  "facebook_id": "1051400994880427",
  "facebook_token": "CAAX3UySfMDcBAFs8glgjz9p1Qdt0M1zwRrmZB9y4WkEPOEldIM5BKVURut8pcg9ios6GiZBschXWBKCqM6HdyZCIxkih6Rwh2SSABrzAHZCzGZBqcISDIlUwnNp73zF8PEZAgXKdzhZAQtfjZAeawUlAHTNpt2RyXTPoeH0ETj8jSclIxMSXPxfbDlnmNjoJXVwZD",
  "facebook_profile_url": "",
  "facebook_avatar": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/1051400994880427/picture?width=1920",
  "google_id": "112519651577038840839",
  "google_token": "ya29.MQLD4wmUQSqGyMVENv8mrko-tvsqg3aLibdy5m-KWBp-HqP5liYB8GlWvSC4c1ZXka3YRRgA2dX40Q",
  "google_profile_url": "https://plus.google.com/+NazirHussain91",
  "google_avatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nLaXbUtBV0g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QaM3CzCJxlM/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "twitter_id": "832857385",
  "twitter_token": "832857385-2PqAa48RffL2Yl7ZNJinBhIawMmH56amI54OBklR",
  "twitter_profile_url": "",
  "twitter_avatar": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2626032008/hzd0ynsei7qjpyobaklw.jpeg",
  "role": "author",
  "activity_stream": [
    {
      "id": "14",
      "user_id": "49",
      "post": "Test Post",
      "created_at": "2015-11-13 04:51:53",
      "updated_at": "2015-11-13 04:51:53",
      "deleted_at": null,
      "activity_stream_comments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "post_id": "14",
          "user_id": "49",
          "comment": "This is my first comment",
          "created_at": "2015-11-19 10:49:13",
          "updated_at": "2015-11-19 10:49:13",
          "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "post_id": "14",
          "user_id": "49",
          "comment": "This is my second comment that I edited as well",
          "created_at": "2015-11-19 11:03:01",
          "updated_at": "2015-11-20 11:35:04",
          "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "post_id": "14",
          "user_id": "30",
          "comment": "This is another test comment",
          "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
          "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
          "deleted_at": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "user_id": "49",
      "post": "This is my first post",
      "created_at": "2015-11-13 06:23:24",
      "updated_at": "2015-11-13 06:23:24",
      "deleted_at": null,
      "activity_stream_comments": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Now there are two questions : 1. How to use orderBy and 2. In the post and comment level how to get user name along with user id at the same time because querying again is not at all a good idea.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Give us some of your code "which is not giving you your desired output"

Comment: updated the query in my question.

Comment: You state "Eloquent" in your title, but your code is anything but. Why not use Laravel's incredible relationship abilities, it would tidy all of this up! As it stands I don't see why you've opted to build your queries this way, when you could just use: `ActivityStream->with(['user', 'posts'])` then add a relationship to post for comments. Simple.

Comment: Loki would you be please  elaborate a bit more and provide some pieces that helps?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NazirHussain `Add relationship between your tables` so that you can make it done !

Comment: @LokiSinclair  I have updated my question as suggested by you and looking forward for further help.

Comment: @NazirHussain, Ok, i will read and will try to help you in few min

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Updated my question based on relationship.